# How to create UI for iPhone 4 in iOS 6 (XCode 4.5)?

Tags: ios5, ios6, iphone-4, iphone-5

I have to create a new app and I am using X Code 4.5 and iOS 6 but when I am creating a UIViewController class with XIB, it is giving me the view of iPhone 5. I understand that but I want to create UI for iPhone 4 as well. How can I add the XIB for iPhone 4?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think so that the XIB file can be changed for iPhone4 and iPhone5. I think you just need to set the `UIComponents` in the XIB file, taking into account the iPhone4 screen size and set the frame of `UIComponents` inside the frame i.e `320*480` for iPhone4. Leave the rest of space empty. It will work for iPhone 4. And if you want the application to run for iPhone5 also then just set the property `Use AutoLayout` on. Dats it..

Comment: I need to create app for both the iPhones i.e., iPhone 4 and iPhone 5.

Comment: Just use the property `AutoLayout`.. That will be it.

Comment: If I will select that option then app will not run on the iOS version less than iOS6 because it will give the following error, "Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint"